# ParseJSON array

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am trying to achieve the following. I have JSON with array:

`apicall = { "CallID":"123", "Response":[ { "Header1":value1, "Header2":value2, "Header3":value3 } ]}`

And I would like to parse the Response into a separate array:

`var Response =  [ { "Header1":value1, "Header2":value2, "Header3":value3 } ]`

I try the following but keep getting error:

`var Response = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(apicall.Response);`

Any idea please?

Comment: So is your `apiCall` variable of a type  `string` or an `object`? If it is already a type of `object` you don't need to `ParseJSON` it then. If it is a `string` then you need to `var myVar Platform.Function.ParseJSON(apicall)` then you can access `myVar.Response`

Comment: How to know if it’s a string or object?

Comment: You could do `console.log(typeof(apiCall))` which should print out the type of data stored in the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding upon my comment above

```
//if Object
var apicall = { "CallID":"123", "Response":[ { "Header1":value1, "Header2":value2, "Header3":value3 } ]}

//Then you could just do this
var Response = apicall.Response;

//if String
var apicall = '{ "CallID":"123", "Response":[ { "Header1":value1, "Header2":value2, "Header3":value3 } ]}'

//then you would have to do this
var myObj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(apicall);

var Response = myObj.Response;
```